# JAVA Check if multiple numbers are the same?

Tags: java, random, dice

I am pretty new to Java, so i'm just trying some stuff out..

I am trying to figure out, how to check how many rolls it will take to get 6 sixes. (Yahtzee)

I've tried to use the &&, but it doesn't let me check for all 6 dices, it just stops when it hits the first 6'er.

I have tried something like this, but it didn't work out..

```
while (die.getDie1() != 6 && die.getDie2() != 6 && die.getDie3() != 6 && die.getDie4() != 6
            && die.getDie5() != 6 && die.getDie6() != 6) {

        die.roll(6);

    }

    System.out.println("It took " + die.getCount() + " rolls to get a yahtzee!");
```

Can anyone help with a solution?

Comment: You need to use || not &&, because you need the loop to repeat if even one of those numbers in not 6.

Comment: Not relevant to the code, but in [Yahtzee](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yahtzee) you only roll 5 dice, and a "yahtzee" is any five-of-a-kind; it doesn't need to be sixes.

Comment: Oh my god! I can't believe i didn't think of that.. I was so focused on the && that i forgot the ||..

Comment: It works now.. Thanks so much Siddhartha

Answer (score 1):

You need to use logical `or` in this case (java markdown is `||`). Because if you use `and`, the condition is true only if all numbers are different from 6 at the same time. If you roll one six, the loop breaks off because no longer all dies are different from 6. You need to eliminate the possibility of any rolls being different from 6 at the same time.

So that is where `or` comes in. You can roll 6 on the first die, but because another condition is "or die2!=6" it evaluates as true, because obviously die2 is not equal to six. Only when all dies are equal to 6, the loop breaks off, because no die is different from 6.

Basically the while loop goes through the tree like this and if it gets only one yes, it continues, because it needs to have all noes: Is die1=!6? no. Is die2!=6? No. Is die3=!6? Yes. Red flag. Ok then, I will loop again. If you use `and` instead, the loop gets more brattyand goes in inverse looking for yes to to continue looping the cycle and breaks of at first no: Is die1=!6? Yes. Is die2!=6? No. Ok see ya! But wait, what if die3!=6...? Nope, I don't care.

Hope you see the flaw in your logic now.

Answer (score 0):

The logic is wrong. Your condition checks if **all** dies are **not** 6 and breaks off as soon as one is six, so `dice1Not6 AND dice2Not6 AND ...`. You want: `dice1Not6 OR dice2Not6 OR ...`. This will only evaluate to `false`, if **all** dices are 6.

In Java:

```
while(die.getDie1() != 6 || die.getDie2() != 6 || ...){
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, you have 6 dies with you..and you want to know how many rolls have to be made so that all of them end up with the number 6 on them at the same time.

You can do something like this:

```
while( true ) // Run forever, until all 6 dies have the same number '6'.
{
    if( die.getDie1() == 6 && die.getDie2() == 6 && die.getDie3() == 6 && die.getDie4() == 6
            && die.getDie5() == 6 && die.getDie6() == 6) 
{
    System.out.println( "Print the count here" );
    break;
}

 die.roll(6); 

}
```